# Register date on domain server is wrong,

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I have the value of the date, By user, captured with the following instructions in jquery:

```
            //$("#fecha").val() , is the date 
            var fechaAux = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", $("#fecha").val());

            var offsetMiliseconds = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
            var fecha = new Date(fechaAux + offsetMiliseconds);
```

[image: format dd/MM/yyyy]

But when register on the server (WINHOST domain server), it registers on sql server 2014 minus one day.

[image]

Why register minus one day? , if the date of the day in sql server returns correctly?

Comment: Looking at your code, you're adding the offset, and an offset can be negative. I'd start looking there.

Comment: `fecha` is UTC time which can differ than local based on `TimeZone`.